# Is Oracle abandoning MySQL development?

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 was a very minor update, and there's no info on a MySQL 5.8 or 6.0.

The Ubuntu maintainers didn't even bother to upgrade MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 in the recent Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release.

Has MySQL reached the end of its lifecycle? Is the future all about JSON and NoSQL Databases?

Comment: Even if MySQL were at the end of its lifecycle, that doesn't mean the future is "all about JSON and NoSQL Databases".

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is still VERY actively developed in it's open source form. You know it by the name MariaDB

https://mariadb.org/

Answer (score 0):

The evil dictator is at it again. Oracle only bought Sun for its hardware and Java. It has no business interest to develop MySql. They may not kill it but sure as hell ain't helping it.

Good thing the developers saw it coming, see MariaDB.